# TFS 2013: How to Create Alerts for Unfinished Work Items when a Sprint Ends

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools, tfs-alerts

Is there a way to set up custom alerts on TFS? I already use the web interface to create alerts, but I need to create custom ones that are not based on work item fields only, but also on the current and past iterations. I know that Power Tools used to have an Alert Explorer in previous versions of Visual Studio, but I don't know if it would have supported what I am trying to do.

Essentially, this is what I need:
An alert that notifies users of unfinished work items assigned to them when the current iteration (sprint in my case) ends.

I know some of you might be concerned about TFS not knowing what the current sprint is, but I have used this workaround http://intellitect.com/transitioning-between-sprintsiterations-with-tfs/ so I don't believe it's an issue.

I know I could simply query for unfinished items and move them to another iteration (sprint) in Excel, but we are trying to get into the habit of getting everyone to finish their work on time, and if not, as quickly as possible, and the notifications would go a long way in helping with that.

Would there even be a way to do this via the TFS API or through the TeamFoundation PowerShell modules? I have searched extensively but I can't seem to find an answer to this question. Any help even with a work-around solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get people into the habit of updating their work items then this will cause you more issue than it fixes. They are not doing it because they do not see the value.

However you could write a TfsJob that sends the emails. It would need to be Scheduled job that checks to see if there is outstanding work...

This should get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisid/archive/2010/02/15/introducing-the-tfs-background-job-agent-and-service.aspx

However what you have is a people problem that cant be solved by tooling.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying that it is a people problem, but we have only recently implemented TFS so the point is to get people into the habit of updating their work items regularly. I will definitely look into the solution you gave me for the time being. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

what I like is getting a job thing, whether a SQL server one or a windows service, running, then manipulate workitems by myself.